# VBA apparent timing issues

Tags: html, vba, timing

I have made a form to copy and paste html into so I can extract some elements from it.  Nevermind that I should be using WebDriver or something to scrape the data because my workplace wont allow me to download any software.

Anyway, when I step through the code below, there are no issues, and it prints out all the ids of the desired elements to the immediate window as expected.  However, if I just run it without breakpoints or stepping through, the program freezes.  I have tried various loops to ensure that the data is set for html1, and for htmlElements, and I have tried the win32 sleep function, and that doesnt work.  I have also tried sending the lengths of the html1 and htmlElements to the immediate window, and they display the desired lengths as well.

I really don't know where the issue is, but the code below only works when stepping through.

```vb
Private Sub txtEnterHTML_Change()

Dim html1 As HTMLDocument
Dim htmlElements As Object
Dim htmlElement As Object
Dim formsAccumulator As String
Dim formsArray As Variant
Dim i As Long

     Set html1 = CreateObject("htmlfile")

     html1.body.innerHTML = UserForm1.txtEnterHTML.Value

     Set htmlElements = html1.getElementsByClassName("myDataLabel")

     For Each htmlElement In htmlElements
          formsAccumulator = formsAccumulator & htmlElement.ID & "|"
     Next htmlElement

     formsAccumulator = Left(formsAccumulator, Len(formsAccumulator) - 1)

     formsArray = Split(formsAccumulator, "|")

     For i = 0 To UBound(formsArray)
          Debug.Print formsArray(i)
     Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The program freezes. Ok, but how? What is available in the Applciation at that time? This help to search for the answer.

Comment: add a debug.print statement between most of the code statements to display an indication of which line is the hold up.

Comment: @Black cat nothing is available.   I can't get it to give me back control such as through Ctrl+C.  I have to close down the app completely, usually through task manager.

Comment: @igittr I tried various versions of that, and it seems to be fine.  In fact, it often will get all the way to formsAccumulator = Left(...) because it never builds the string and it has a Len of zero.

Comment: Try with an added a `DoEvents` statement before and after the statement to obtain the body text.  I am not sure how this text field (or other type of field?) obtains the web page, and cannot create a test to recreate this condition.

Comment: I tried with that and what I have learned is that if I change it to operate on a button instead of on a change event with the text box, it is more reliable.   I don't know why, so if anybody has an explanation, I would appreciate it.